# Error while building a Qt 4 project using cmake

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, cmake, qtgui

I have create a simple Qt 4 project, and now, I want to make use of CMake as the build system. My project files are as follow:

```
├── about.cpp
├── about.h
├── about.ui
├── alldeb_en.ts
├── alldeb_id.ts
├── AllDebInstaller.pro
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── dialog.cpp
├── dialog.h
├── dialog.ui
└── main.cpp
```

My CMakeLists.txt file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
PROJECT(alldeb-installer)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})

QT4_WRAP_UI(UISrcs dialog.ui about.ui)
#QT4_WRAP_CPP(MOCSrcs dialog.h about.h)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

ADD_EXECUTABLE(alldeb-installer main.cpp dialog.cpp about.cpp ${MOCSrcs} ${UISrcs})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(alldeb-installer ${QT_LIBRARIES})

ADD_LIBRARY(terjemah ${sources}
${UISrcs})

qt4_create_translation(qm_files
${terjemah_SRCS} alldeb_en.ts alldeb_id.ts
)

install(TARGETS alldeb-installer DESTINATION bin)
```

But something still messed. I don't know what's wrong with about.cpp.
the 'error: stray ‘\nnn’ in program' appear many times.
here is the screenshot:

[image]

image: http://i62.tinypic.com/1gm6ty.png

Please someone explain it. Thanks.

**EDIT**
oh, it's surprising and embarassing, I've found that about.cpp contains many unknown characters.
here is the screenshot:

image: http://i62.tinypic.com/2iql2qh.png

it must be because the wrong CMakeLists.txt configuration before.

but actually about.cpp only contains:

```
#include "about.h"
#include "ui_about.h"

About::About(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::About)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

About::~About()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: It probably has nothing to do with the pasted cmake file, but your code. Check if it has some stray characters for some reason. You could try pasting the about.cpp here.

Comment: previously, I've googling about it, but I'm sure that the about.cpp didn't contain stray characters. but after I checked it, you're right, it has stray characters. by the way, actually I want your opinion about my Cmakelists. is it okay in that way?

Comment: It is OK'ish. I would personally use a variable for the source files, but it is not a biggie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a cmake issue, but corruption with your `about.cpp` file. It has got stray characters for one reason or another. The solution is "uncorrupt it", and then it will work with the same cmake file.

Comment: Yes, sir, you're right. I've changed about.cpp with the original one. And it successfully built. Thanks.